# long std::initializer_list with many elements for testing

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, stdinitializerlist

My class needs to impose an upper limit on the number of elements of one of its data members, which happens to be a container.

One of the constructors of my class takes an std::initializer_list as a parameter to initialize that container data member.

A unit test needs to verify that the upper limit is in place. For this I need to try to invoke my constructor with an initializer list with 1025 elements.

Is there a better (= more readable) way to create this 1025-element initializer_list, than having a braced literal list of 1025 elements in the test code?

(The data type of the elements is always unsigned short (uint16_t), my class is not a template.)

Comment: You could make the class a template with the maximum number of elements the only template parameter (defaulting to 1024), but test for smaller numbers (say 4), when all you need is a `std::initializer_list` of 5 elements, not 1025.

Comment: Interesting. I have a little bit of a bad feeling with this, because then, strictly speaking, I would verify the behaviour of another class (or template instantiation), not the class that I actually use in production. But something to consider.

Comment: you could use a template specification to generate the 1024 elements in compile time.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava If you know how this is done, and it's more readable than a long literal list, then please post it as an answer

Comment: Do those numbers have any meaning, or they can be generated randomly?

Comment: @KjMag For this unit test, only the number of elements is important, not the elements' values. They can be all 0, or random, or a natural sequence, or anything else, it makes no difference to the test. Of course, if I have to settle for a literal list, then for best (but still bad) readability I would choose a sequence from 0 to 1024 or from 1 to 1025. But I hope someone here can up with something shorter and more readable.

Comment: Ok, and is it ok if the list gets generated at runtime, or do you need something that is generated at compile time?

Comment: Anything that works and is readable will be fine.

Comment: In the meantime this question has been answered in such a way that I have nothing to add ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go for template recursion, or fancy "repeat" macros, you are possibly going to be hit by static recursion limits, which is going to complicate your implementation even more than usual.

With this in mind, I think the simplest and best approach is just to define some nested macros, i.e.

```
#define ZEROS_10 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
#define ZEROS_50 ZEROS_10, ZEROS_10, ZEROS_10, ZEROS_10, ZEROS_10
#define ZEROS_250 ZEROS_50, ZEROS_50, ZEROS_50, ZEROS_50, ZEROS_50
#define ZEROS_1K ZEROS_250, ZEROS_250, ZEROS_250, ZEROS_250

FooType f{ ZEROS_1K, ZEROS_10, ZEROS_10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Comment: Looks good. Simple, very readable, achieves desired result. Thank you!